# If copper is insoluble in excess NaOH, does it mean it is soluble in NaOH when not in excess?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I don't understand, does it mean when i add a little bit of NaOH, there will be completely no precipitate/ it will dissolve?

Comment: No. Some compounds say $\ce{X(OH)2}$ will form an anion complex in strong (excess) NaOH such as $\ce{X(OH)4^{2-}}$

Comment: On the other hand, I do not quite understand this question :). Please edit to clarify.

Comment: I don't see why this question is unclear to many. Although the question has not been nicely framed, it is still clear that the OP is talking about the specific precipitation reactions where adding excess of reagent dissolves the precipitate.

Answer (score 3):

When less amount of $\ce{NaOH}$ is added initially, $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ will be formed and leave the solution as a precipitate. But when excess $\ce{NaOH}$ is added, $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ will form soluble complex with excess $\ce{NaOH}$.

Complex formation increased the solubility of $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$.

Now, this happened only because copper hydroxide had a tendency to form complex with ex $\ce{NaOH}$ and complex formation was favourable in this case.  Adding excess reagent will only lead to solubility of precipitate if the precipitate has a tendency to form a complex with excess of that reagent.

**If "X" is insoluble in excess reagent "Y", then it WILL NOT BE  soluble in "Y" when not in excess.**

**If "X" is soluble in excess reagent "Y", then it will only be soluble in "Y" if "X" has a tendency to form complex with "Y" and complex formation is favourable.**

You will come across a lot such reactions in inorganic chemistry.

e.g $\ce{AgCl}$ dissolves in excess ammonia due to formation of silver-ammonia complex.