# Why is the formation of lead (II) iodide precipitate favoured over that of the tetraiodo plumbate (II) complex ion in low concentrations of iodide?

Tags: equilibrium, solubility

I was wondering why

$$\ce{Pb2+ + 2I- <=> PbI2}$$

occurs in low $[\ce{I-}]$, however when $[\ce{I-}]$ is in excess, $\ce{PbI4^2-}$ is produced with

$$\ce{Pb2+ + 4I- <=> [PbI4]^2-}$$

Why is the formation of complex ion "favoured"? Furthermore, since the formation of insoluble precipitate will reduce entropy, wouldn't the formation of insoluble precipitate be favoured?

Comment: @ Ong What do you mean by "Why is there no formation of complex ion "favoured"?"

Comment: @Mockingbird Hi there Mockingbird, my auto correct screwed up my sentence a bit. To correct myself, I wanted to know why formation of soluble tetraiodo plumbate(ii) ion complex is more observed than the formation of insoluble lead (ii) iodide (ie why the overall effect of added $\ce{I-}$ is the dissolving of ppt)

Comment: When $\ce{Cl^-}$ is in greater concentration, there are just enough ions to favor the 2nd reaction.

Comment: @Mockingbird is there any principle behind this?

Comment: Well, the rule of thumb is when you need to have grater number reactants for some reaction the greater concentration will work better.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67452/if-copper-is-insoluble-in-excess-naoh-does-it-mean-it-is-soluble-in-naoh-when-n